# Object does not support property stripTime in fullcalender

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Hi i am using Fullcalender in Bootstrap modal.But its not rendering the calender in modal window.When i tried to debug it says "Object does not support property stripTime".I have included moment.js and made sure that its loaded before fullcalender.js.

Comment: I guess u need to specify exactly what extension are u using or make a demo plunk...